# SQL Server 2008 setup issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster, failovercluster

I am setting up SQL Server 2008 fail over cluster on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I met with the following issue during setup process. Here is detailed message, any ideas what is wrong?

The resource "SQL Network Name (TestServer)" private property "RequireKerberos" set to the value "1" error. Error: The value is not within the expected range.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtType=0x1251FB33

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this forum post they mention at least 2 solution to solve it.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic723728-391-1.aspx